Get cursor position and trigger function when the cursor change among monitors
I have an application and want to trigger an function when the cursor change among the primary monitor (laptop) and a second monitor. Basically I've implemented the page PointerPressed, PointerMoved and PointerReleased and I want to trigger the PointerReleased when the cursor pass to the second monitor.
I've tried to use DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView(); to get information of current display. But actually I don't know how treat it correctly.

You're not using WinUI3's DisplayInformation class but the UWP one, you must use this one in the Microsoft.Graphics.Display namespace https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.graphics.display.displayinformation and CreateForWindowId or CreateForDisplayId methods

DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView() is no longer supported in WinUI 3 in Desktop.
I suggest you should use the methods in the Doc:DisplayInformation Class
And you should call different APIs depending on the information you want to get of the display. Refer to the threads:
https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4205
https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/4228
